# Auto-save local folder to iCloud Drive

Tags: icloud

I prefer to have all my files saved locally on my Mac, be it Desktop, Documents, etc.

[image]

But there is one specific folder (/Users/mohitlamba/Documents/thesis/) and I wish that whenever any change is made to the contents of this folder, or some new file is added to this folder **a copy** of this folder should be saved/synced to iCloud.

Is there a way to do it without syncing my whole Documents folder to iCloud. I can change the location of `thesis` folder if it helps.

--- Update

I have already tried the following and does not work for me,

1. Save folder in iCloud section which appears in the Finder sidbar.
2. Now work with folder saved in iCloud.

Basically, the folder contains LATEX files which compile alright when the folder is in local storage. And when I compile LATEX files stored in iCloud compilation errors comes up. Thus I prefer working with folder saved in the local system but a **backup** of it be automatically stored to iCloud when changes are made.

The specific error which comes up when compiling LATEX file stored in iCloud is that file address in iCloud have `~` (`/Users/mohitlamba/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/thesis/2-mainmatter/chapters/monocular.tex`) while locally stored files do not have.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable iCloud Drive in iCloud preferences.
   [Set up iCloud Drive - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204025)
2. Store files you wish to synchronise using iCloud Drive in the iCloud Drive folder shown in Finder sidebar.

   > iCloud Drive appears in the Finder sidebar, where you can select it to see its contents. […] It can also contain folders you create and files you save or move into iCloud Drive or its folders.

   [Work with folders and files in iCloud Drive - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl1a02d711/mac)
3. Make sure Optimize Mac Storage is disabled in iCloud preferences, which will ensure your Mac keeps all iCloud files locally as well as in iCloud.

This is separate to enabling Desktop & Documents in your screenshot, which would synchronise your existing folders to iCloud Drive.

Comment: I had already tried 1 and 2. I am using it for LATEX. Latex compiles OK when file stored on local system but not when saved in iCloud drive. Thats why this solution does not work for me. Instead I prefer having file in local system and automatically update it to iCloud when changes are made to the folder.